# Formula and percentages

Tags: random, dice, percentages

I need help making a formula. Here is the basic concept: I have 1 twenty-sided die (from now on 1d20) and another 16-sided die (1d16). I roll each, and the die which displays the lowest number "wins". This math I can do, and it is obvious that the 1d16 will roll a lower number more often than the 1d20. However if I roll 2d20 vs. 1d16. Which has the better odds of winning (i.e. rolling a lower number)? Simultaneously, a separate but related question of mine is which has a better odds of rolling a 1. 
The reason I want to formulate a formula is because the above is part of a prototype game mechanic, and I am curious as to which die combinations have technically better chances of "beating" an opponent. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is the outcome of the 2d20 the lowest of the two?

Comment: As a general note:  as the rules of a game get more and more intricate, it often becomes necessary (or at least convenient) to answer questions like this via simulation rather than exact computation.  To be sure, this one is easy enough to work out exactly but even simple games often lead to problems which are too complex to sort out precisely.

Comment: @lulu Agreed ... And even if we compute the average outcome of the 2d20 (i.e. take the average of the minimum of the two), and find it to be lower than the average outcome of thew 1d16, then I believe we still can't immediately infer that the 2d20 is more likely to have a lower number than the 1d16 when 'competing' against each other .. is that right?

Comment: @Bram28  Yes, reasoning from the average is very treacherous.  If, say, my die has a $0$ on one face and $2's$ on the other $5$ and yours has $1.75$ on all six faces then my average is lower than yours, but you win five sixths of the times.

Comment: @lulu Ah yes, good example! Thanks, I figured as much ... which is why I wasn't going to touch that one with a 10 foot pole in my Answer :)

Comment: Ah, that's a very good idea. I will explore this wonderful internet for some sort of simulator, that should give some good data. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your second question is easy to answer: You are more likely to roll a $1$ with $2$ $D20$'s. The probability of that is $1$ minus the probability of not getting a $1$, and so:

$P(1|2D20) = 1-P(1') = 1-\frac{19}{20}\cdot\frac{19}{20}=0.0975$

While the probability of rolling a $1$ with one $D16$ is:

$P(1|1D16) = \frac{1}{16} = 0.0625$

For the other question: which has better odds of getting the lower number: that's a little nasty since you need to pick the minimum of the two... Intuitively I would think one of the $2$ $D20$ is likely to 'beat' the $D16$  ... but you'll have to do the math.

Comment: Thank you much for your assistance! Yes I am not 'mathematically inclined'  so I've been searching out assistance and while doing so have been told that the math can get quite nasty. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

if you roll a d16 and a d20

$\frac {16}{320}$ the dice are equal

$\dfrac {\sum_\limits{n=1}^{15} n + 16\cdot 4}{320} = \frac {184}{320}$ the d16 wins

$\dfrac {\sum_\limits{n=1}^{15} n}{320} = \frac {120}{320}$ the d20 wins

1 d16 vs 2d20.

the d16 has a $\frac 1{16}$ chance to roll any number (call it $n$ in [1,16])

A win for the 2 d20 the first d20 is lower than $n$ is $\frac {n-1}{20}$
or the first d20 is greater than or equal to $n$ and the second die is less than n.

$\frac {20(n-1) + (21-n)(n-1)}{400} = \frac {-n^2 +42n - 41}{400}$

2 d 20 wins:

$\frac {1}{6400} \sum_\limits{n=1}^{16} -n^2 +42n - 41\\
\frac {1}{6400} (-\frac 16 (16)(17)(33) + \frac 12 42(16)(17) - 41*16 = \frac {3560}{6400}$

2 d 20 loses:

$\frac {1}{6400} \sum_\limits{n=1}^{16} (20-n)^2 = \frac {2456}{6400}$

Tie 
$\frac 1{6400} \sum_\limits{n=1}^{16} 2(21-n) - 1 = \frac{384}{6400}$

Comment: The OP was asking about rolling *two* D20's .... not sure how he defined the outcome for that  though ... I assume the minimum ...

Comment: Nice! Glad I didn't even try ... :)